# Restore cursor position after .replace()

Tags: javascript, input, cursor

My biggest problem is that after it's replaced, the cursor defaults to the end of the textarea. That's no issue if I'm typing, but if I'm going back and editing, it's really annoying. Here's what I tried (the id of the textarea is "area")

```
var el = e.area;

  position = el.selectionStart; // Capture initial position

      el.value = el.value.replace('\u0418\u0410', '\u042F');
  el.selectionEnd = position;    // Set the cursor back to the initial position.
```

Comment: So, the length of the replacement text can be different from the length of the typed text, right?

Comment: Hi- yeah, it can be. One of the most common uses of .replace() is to simply remove a word/phrase from a string. For example, .replace('word', '') would replace 'word' by '', which removes it. This doesn't actually make a difference with the cursor- it moves to the end no matter the length.

Comment: But it makes a difference for the solution. Simple restoring the original position will not put the cursor back correctly if the length has changed.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Oh, you make a good point.... However, I think it should be an easy fix. See, every .replace() take two characters and makes it one, so simply reducing the space by one should work. Not sure how that would work, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following code snippet. In its current form, it replaces `==` with `+`, but it allows to replace any string with another one, shorter or longer.

In order to maintain the cursor position, you have to save and restore the `selectionStart` and the `selectionEnd`. An offset is calculated to account for the difference in length between the two strings, and the number of occurrences before the cursor.

The use of `setTimeout` ensures that the newly typed character has been inserted in the text before doing the processing.

```js
var area = document.getElementById("area");

var getCount = function (str, search) {
    return str.split(search).length - 1;
};

var replaceText = function (search, replaceWith) {
    if (area.value.indexOf(search) >= 0) {
        var start = area.selectionStart;
        var end = area.selectionEnd;
        var textBefore = area.value.substr(0, end);
        var lengthDiff = (replaceWith.length - search.length) * getCount(textBefore, search);
        area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
        area.selectionStart = start + lengthDiff;
        area.selectionEnd = end + lengthDiff;
    }
};

area.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        replaceText("==", "+");
    }, 0)
});
```

```html
<textarea id="area" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi- not sure why, but this script only works sometimes. It works for me if I try "Run code snippet", and it works on JSFiddle, but nowhere else. I've tried multiple HTML editors, tried downloading the script as a .html, and even uploading it to my site. Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: The script block must be at the end of the body, after the DOM elements.

Comment: I tried that- I put the textarea before the script, no luck

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Nothing else is needed than what we see in the code snippet. I went to [this test site](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro), inserted the `textarea` and the `<script>...</script>` code block and it worked.

Comment: It was my computer- a simple cache clear solved the issue. Thanks!